# Login as Administrator on Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, windows-server-2008-r2, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to install a certain software on an Azure Virtual Machine, however it fails indicating that I don't have Administration privileges, even though I chooose the "Run as administrator" option. How can I login as an Administrator on an Azure Virtual Machine? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://serverfault.com/questions/111650/how-can-i-find-out-what-ad-groups-im-a-member-of

The above link will tell you what groups you belong to as the user in the system.

If you are running as the default user setup for the azure VM then you will be the Administrator on the machine. If have been granted access by another user to the box, just ask them to upgrade your rights.

You should also see if in the event log there is an permissions error for the install of the software or any other error to suggest why your software cannot be installed. Maybe a misleading error.

I would also contact the application provider and check that they support the Azure environment.

hths, good luck.